# mapply over different columns of multiple data

Tags: r, mapply

I have a function, which takes two vectors and computes a numeric value (like `cor` correlation would do). However, I have two datasets with around 6000 columns (the two datasets have the same dimensions), where the function should return one vector with the values of the correlation.

The code with a loop would look like this:

```
set.seed(123)
m=matrix(rnorm(9),ncol=3)
n=matrix(rnorm(9,10),ncol=3)

colNumber=dim(m)[2]
ReturnData=rep(NA,colNumber)

for (i in 1:colNumber){
    ReturnData[i]=cor(m[,i],n[,i])
}
```

This works fine, but for efficiency reasons I want to use the apply-family, obviously, the mapply function.

However,`mapply(cor,m,n)` returns a vector with length 9 of `NA`s, where it should return:

```
> ReturnData
[1]  0.1247039 -0.9641188  0.5081204
```

**EDIT/SOLUTION**

The solution as given by @akrun was the usage of dataframes instead of matrices.

Furthermore, a speed test between the two proposed solutions showed, that the `mapply`-version is faster than `sapply`:

```
require(rbenchmark) 
set.seed(123)
#initiate the two dataframes for the comparison 
m=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10^6),ncol=100))
n=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10^6),ncol=100))
#indx is needed for the sapply function to get the column numbers
indx=seq_len(ncol(m)) 
benchmark(s1=mapply(cor, m,n), s2=sapply(indx, function(i) cor(m[,i], n[,i])), order="elapsed", replications=100)

#   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 2   s2          100    4.16    1.000      4.15        0         NA        NA
# 1   s1          100    4.33    1.041      4.32        0         NA        NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your dataset is `matrix`, the `mapply` would loop through each element instead of each column.  To avoid that, convert to dataframe.  I am not sure how efficient this would be for big datasets.

```
mapply(cor, as.data.frame(m), as.data.frame(n))
#     V1         V2         V3 
#0.1247039 -0.9641188  0.5081204
```

Another option is to use `sapply` without converting to `data.frame`

```
 indx <- seq_len(ncol(m))
 sapply(indx, function(i) cor(m[,i], n[,i]))
 #[1]  0.1247039 -0.9641188  0.5081204
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. The `data.frame()` was the solution.

Comment: I ran a Benchmark over the two different versions. `mapply` seems to be way faster...



`require(rbenchmark)
set.seed(123)
m=data.frame(v1=rnorm(10^6),v2=rnorm(10^6),v3=rnorm(10^6))
n=data.frame(v1=rnorm(10^6),v2=rnorm(10^6),v3=rnorm(10^6))
indx=seq_len(ncol(m))
benchmark( s1 <- mapply(cor, m,n), s2 <- sapply(indx, function(i) cor(m[,i], n[,i])), order="elapsed", replications=2)`

Returns elapsed time of 0.1 for mapply and 0.14 for sapply.

Comment: @David Thanks for sharing the benchmarks. You could update that it in your post.